# Testing image on Tensorflow Mnist Model using checkpoints

Tags: python, tensorflow, mnist, tensorflow-serving

I am a newbie to TensorFlow.I got the mnist train sample and I want to test an image by generating the checkpoints.I referred to Tensorflow documentation and generated checkpoints and tried to test a sample image by accessing the softmax layer.But given an image [number-9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QL4C.png)  **softmax gives me an invalid one-hot-encoded array like 'array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32)'**,when I tried to access the softmax using

**softmax = graph.get_tensor_by_name('SOFTMAX:0').**

I tried testing with different images,it didn't give proper result for any of them.

1.I asssumed, softmax will give me an array of probabilities.Am I right?

2.Am I saving the model properly?

3.Am I accessing the correct layer for testing an input?

4.Is there anything further to be added in my testing/training code?

Sorry for posting everything here.

This is my train code:

```
from __future__ import division, print_function, unicode_literals
import tensorflow as tf
from time import time
import numpy as np
import os
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage
from scipy import misc

from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

logs_train_dir = '/home/test/Logs'

def weight_variable(shape,name):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial,name=name+'_weight')

def bias_variable(shape,name):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial,name=name+'_bias')

def conv2d(x, W):
    return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x,name):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1], strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME',name=name+'_max_pool')

# correct labels

y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

# reshape the input data to image dimensions

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784],name='X')#Input Tensor
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1],name='X_Image')

# build the network

W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32],'W_conv1')
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32],'b_conv1')
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1,name='h_conv1')
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1,'h_pool1')
W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64],'W_conv2')
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64],'b_conv2')
h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2,name='h_conv2')
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2,'W_conv2')
W_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024],name='wc1')
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024],name='b_fc1')
h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,name='KEEP_PROB')
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)
W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10],name='w_fc2')
b_fc2 = bias_variable([10],name='b_fc2')
y_conv=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2,name='SOFTMAX')#Softmax Tensor

# define the loss function
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y_conv), reduction_indices=[1]),name='CROSS_ENTROPY')
loss_summary = tf.summary.scalar('loss_sc',cross_entropy)

# define training step and accuracy

train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1),name='CORRECT_PRED')
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32),name='ACCURACY')
accuracy_summary = tf.summary.scalar('accuracy_sc', accuracy)

# create a saver
saver = tf.train.Saver()

# initialize the graph
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
summary_op = tf.summary.merge_all()

sess = tf.Session()
train_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(logs_train_dir, sess.graph)
sess.run(init)

# train

print("Startin Burn-In...")
for i in range(500):
    input_images, correct_predictions = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
    if i % 100 == 0:
        train_accuracy = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: input_images, y_: correct_predictions, keep_prob: 1.0})
        print("step %d, training accuracy_a %g" % (i, train_accuracy))

    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: input_images, y_: correct_predictions, keep_prob: 0.5})

print("Starting the training...")
start_time = time()
for i in range(20000):
    input_images, correct_predictions = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
    if i % 100 == 0:
        train_accuracy = sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: input_images, y_: correct_predictions, keep_prob: 1.0})
        print("step %d, training accuracy_b %g" % (i, train_accuracy))
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: input_images, y_: correct_predictions, keep_prob: 0.5})

    summary_str = sess.run(summary_op,feed_dict={x: input_images, y_: correct_predictions, keep_prob: 0.5})
    train_writer.add_summary(summary_str, i)

    print('SAVING CHECKPOINTS......i is ',i)

    if i % 1000 == 0 or (i+1) == 20000:
        checkpoint_path = os.path.join(logs_train_dir,'cnn_new_model.ckpt')
        print('checkpoint_path is ',checkpoint_path)
        saver.save(sess,checkpoint_path,global_step=i)

print("The training took %.4f seconds." % (time() - start_time))
# validate
print("test accuracy %g" % sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={
x: mnist.test.images,
y_: mnist.test.labels,
keep_prob: 1.0}))
```

The accuracy was 0.97.

This is my test code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import scipy.ndimage as ndimage
from scipy import misc
import cv2 as cv

def get_test_image():    
    image = cv.imread('/home/test/Downloads/9.png', 0)
    resized = cv.resize(image, (28,28), interpolation = cv.INTER_AREA)
    image = np.array(resized)
    flat = np.ndarray.flatten(image)    
    reshaped_image = np.reshape(flat,(1, 784))
return reshaped_image


def evaluate_one_image():

    image_array = get_test_image()
    image_array = image_array.astype(np.float32)
    logs_train_dir ='/home/test/Logs'    
    model_path = logs_train_dir+"/cnn_new_model.ckpt-19999"
    detection_graph = tf.Graph()

    with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
        # Load the graph with the trained states
        loader = tf.train.import_meta_graph(model_path+'.meta')
        loader.restore(sess, model_path)

        # Get the tensors by their variable name

        image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('X:0')
        softmax = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('SOFTMAX:0')
        keep_prob = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('KEEP_PROB:0')       

        # Make prediction

        softmax = sess.run(softmax, feed_dict={image_tensor: image_array,keep_prob:0.75}) 

        print('softmax is ', cost_val,'\n\n')
        print('softmax maximum val is ', np.argmax(cost_val))

evaluate_one_image()
```

So when I tested with an image of number 9 ,it gave me the following output:

**softmax is [[ 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]**

**softmax maximum val is 1**

I have no idea,where I am going wrong.Any help would be really useful and greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Dropout isn't used during evaluation/prediction. So you need to set `keep_prob=1`
2. Inspect the pixel values of the input image `image_array`, pixel values should be in the range `[0, 1]`, else you need to normalize the pixel values by subtracting image mean and dividing by the image std

For the function to load image you can add the following lines to normalize

```
def get_test_image():  
    ...  
    image = np.array(resized)
    mean = image.mean()
    std = image.std()
    image = np.subtract(image, mean)
    image = np.divide(image, std)
    image = np.clip(image, 0, 1.000001)
    ...
```

Comment: hi Ishant.Thanks for the reply.I have added the above lines and continued with these two lines: flat = np.ndarray.flatten(image)    
    reshaped_image = np.reshape(flat,(1, 784)).Now 1. image_array has values btw 0-1.2.softmax gives probabilities.But the prediction is not correct.

Comment: might be your model din't converge to generalize well.

Comment: so what shall I add to generalize my model.shall I increase the iterations ?But the accuracy was shown increasing and loss was shown decreasing in tensorboard with 2000 iterations itself.

Comment: you can try `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` as loss function, here don't use the softmax output as logits. `logitts=f.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2)`

Comment: u mean pred =tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2 loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred) ..if so ,should I access this pred for testing??

Comment: more details https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits